# Restart process on event using Salt Stack and beacons

Tags: nginx, salt-stack, reactor, process-monitoring

I successfully configured salt master (with reactor) and minion (with beacon). On minion I have nginx and beacon configuration that watch the  process:

```
beacons:
  service:
    nginx:
      onchangeonly: True
      uncleanshutdown: /run/nginx.pid
```

Event is send and reactor get that event. I try to restart nginx:

```
{% set nginx_running = data['data']['nginx']['running']  %}
{% if not nginx_running %}
restart_nginx:
  local.cmd.run:
  - tgt: {{ data['data']['id'] }}
  - arg:
    - 'pkill nginx'
    - 'systemctl restart nginx'
{% endif %}
```

Problem:

- is that the right way to do it?
- I want to send pkill because if nginx is killed - only root process, worker process are still working
- I got information "ERROR: Specified cmd 'pkill nginx' either not absolute or does not exist

Comment: Not sure about what you're trying to achieve but the symptom should be reasonably easy to address?  In a shell, type `type pkill` and write down its path (on my Ubuntu 14.04 box, it's `/usr/bin/pkill`); then change your script to use the absolute path.  Does this help?

Comment: I tried that - it's the same. I am using RHEL7 if that helps. What I want to achieve is to restart nginx if it fails. I also tries to use beacons: ps:, but with even worse result. Maybe because of this: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/31516